# Undoing define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' ); to repoint to "wp-content/uploads" folder

Tags: attachments, uploads

Is it possible that by setting the “wp-content/uploads” to use a different folder by using `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );` I have effectively changed all the paths on a permanent basis and if that is the case, how do I undo this so that it points back to “wp-content/uploads”?

I thought that just by commenting out the `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );` line out I will sort out a problem I am having where a file I am uploading to WP does not want to download because the URL is not the right path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry. This question was related to Advanced Custom Fields plugin and this question I had there http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/file-download-url-incorrect-cannot-download-uploaded-file/

Seems that `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );` is not affected if you just comment it out in the wp-config file and it does revert back to the “wp-content/uploads” file naturally.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to just change the upload directory you can use something like this:

```
function wp128084_upload_dir( $pathdata ) {
     // change path here
     return $pathdata;
}

add_filter('upload_dir', 'wp128084_upload_dir');
```

and again to remove this you can use this

```
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wp128084_upload_dir');
```